# angular multiple $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, showmodaldialog, mddialog

I work with modal tabs and I have notification pop-up window which is always shown to user when he logs into my application. It contains all events which happends when user was offline. Problem is when i click on any objects from list it close my pop-up window and display new modal tab.

I want to archieve this functionality. When user log in, notification pop-up window will be shown to user and if he clicks on any object it will open another window without closing my notification pop-up window(New events). I want something like that on picture below which I made.

[image: picture to clarify what I want to archieve]

I checked angular material documentation, but there is no demo at all and not even well explained how to work with `multiple: true` option and I dont know exactly how to make it work like I want.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog

This is my code for displaying notification pop-up window.

```
//show new notifications when user log in
    NotificationService.getUnreadedNotifications(function (data) {
        //initialization
        $scope.notification = [];
        $scope.OverAllCount = 0;
        $scope.messageNotification = [];
        $scope.OverAllMessageCount = 0;

        if (data.ProjectNotifications != null) {
            angular.forEach(data.ProjectNotifications, function (key, value) {
                $scope.notification.push(key);
                $scope.OverAllCount = $scope.OverAllCount + 1;
            });
        }

        if (data.TasksNotifications != null) {
            angular.forEach(data.TasksNotifications, function (key, value) {
                $scope.notification.push(key);
                $scope.OverAllCount = $scope.OverAllCount + 1;
            });
        }

        if (data.MessageNotifications != null) {
            angular.forEach(data.MessageNotifications, function (key, value) {
                $scope.OverAllMessageCount = $scope.OverAllMessageCount + 1;
                $scope.messageNotification.push(key);
            });
        }

        popUpNotification();

        $scope.hide = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };

        $scope.answer = function (answer) {
            $mdDialog.hide(answer);
        };

        //mark notifications as readed when user click on notification
        function popUpNotification() {
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: NotificationController,
                templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/PopUpNotification.html',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                //targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                fullscreen: false,
                scope: $scope,
                multiple:true,
                preserveScope: true,
                onComplete: function () {
                    $scope.notificationPopUp = $scope.notification;
                }
            })
            .then(function () {

            }, function () {
                //fail
            });
        }
    });
```

This is code for displaying details of object on which user clicked in new overlaying modal tab

```
        //mark notifications as readed when user click on notification
    $scope.popUpDetail = function (notification, index, ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: NotificationController,
            templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/TaskDetailsDialog.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true,
            fullscreen: false,
            scope: $scope,
            multiple: true,
            preserveScope: true,
            onComplete: function () {
                //was readed => update database
                NotificationResourceService.update({ id: notification.Id }, notification);
                $scope.OverAllCount -= 1;
                $scope.notification.splice(index, 1);

                TaskService.get({ id: notification.EntityId })
                    .$promise.then(function (task) {
                        $scope.task = task;
                    });
            }
        })
        .then(function () {

        }, function () {
            //fail
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow i found working solution for my problem. It might help somebody in future.

Working code:

```
 function popUpNotification() {
            $mdDialog.show({
                templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/PopUpNotification.html',
                clickOutsideToClose: true,
                bindToController: true,
                scope: $scope,  
                preserveScope: true,
                controller: function ($scope, $mdDialog) {
                    $scope.notificationPopUp = $scope.notification;
                    $scope.popUpDetail = function (notification, index, ev) {
                        $mdDialog.show({
                            controller: function ($mdDialog) {
                                this.click = function () {
                                    $mdDialog.hide();
                                }
                            },
                            targetEvent: ev,
                            clickOutsideToClose: true,
                            preserveScope: true,
                            autoWrap: true,
                            skipHide: true,
                            scope: $scope,
                            preserveScope: true,
                            templateUrl: 'app/components/templates/TaskDetailsDialog.html',
                            onComplete: function () {
                                TaskService.get({ id: notification.EntityId })
                                    .$promise.then(function (task) {
                                        $scope.task = task;
                                    });
                            }
                        })
                    }
                },
                autoWrap: false,
            })
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `'multiple: true'` as a parameter:

```
// From plain options
$mdDialog.show({
  multiple: true
});

// From a dialog preset
$mdDialog.show(
  $mdDialog
    .alert()
    .multiple(true)
);
```

From documentation: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog

Answer (score 0):

The key is using `skipHide: true` as parameter in the object we pass into `$mdDialog.show()`. I tried without `multiple: true` and it still works. This parameter has to be passed **into the second** (or nth) dialog. So it will look somethink like this:

```js
// second dialog 
$mdDialog.show({
  // some fields
  skipHide: true,
  //some fields
});
```